# Best clustering algorithm to identify clusters and determine the closet cluster each individual response is near?

Tags: clustering, algorithms

I have a survey where each question is related to a different 'shopper' type (there are 5 types so 5 questions). Each question is either binary (True/False) or scale based.

IE:

```
1. Do you like to shop at our physical location store ? (True/False)

2. Do our discounts entice you to shop more? a. no b. maybe c. yes
```

For each response I convert the answer choice to a numerical value. So True becomes 1, answer choice 2C becomes 3 etc.

At this point, I am clueless as too what clustering algorithm to use so I can create clusters for each of the 'shopper' types and measures each individual survey response submitted to determine a single cluster closet to the responses given and label the response as that cluster.

IE. This individual that submitted the survey response is `'location conscience shopper type'`

Open to any new method of analysis not just clustering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are categorical variables, I would cluster them using the **k-medoids clustering method**. Before applying this method, one-hot encode all the predictors.

See a tutorial here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/k-medoids-clustering-on-iris-data-set-1931bf781e05

Sklearn has an implementation:
https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids.html

Comment: thank you for the response, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please tell me why we need to one-hot encode all predictors? And can you give me a small example of one-hot encoding with the survey example to make sure I am understanding correctly

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at these suggestions 
[Clustering categorical data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13273/clustering-categorical-data)

i havent tried clustering on pure categorical dataset yet however have tried on text data where at the end you end up creating a sparse matrix and have had success there with hierarchical clustering using Wards' method

https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-concept-of-hierarchical-clustering-technique-c6e8243758ec

Although I havent used this one before - but try k-mediods where mediods are identified instead of centroids using means
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-k-medoids-clustering-with-example/